# send email error : Error 550, User account support@mydomain.com has sent too many emails

Tags: email, smtp, cpanel

I have a forum, base on PHP (for many years). 
One user pointed out that in recent days, the email sending system does not work properly.
I went Cpanel (in host) and tried to send an email (with Squirrelmail or Roundcube).

but in Squirrelmail, When I send the email, see the following error :

((
Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
550 User account support@mydomain.com has sent too many emails
))

and in Roundcube :

((
SMTP Error (550): Failed to add recipient "example@yahoo.com" (User account support@mydomain.com has sent too many emails).
))

I've never sent spam e-mails and My website ip is not on the blacklist for emails.
I even created a new email accout (with no special restrictions), but it is also faced with the same error.

Comment: This seems to be a question that the hosting provider should answer. Has little to do with coding.

Answer (score 0):

That means point blank that the host you are trying to send to, has blocked your server. This could be do to spam complaints or other abuse issues, or even because that server is misconfigured. You would need to contact the host in question to ask why they have decided to block your server. You should also check to see if your server has been blacklisted. A good site to use to check that is:

[mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx)

On message, some providers puts aditional information such "has sent too many emails" "Your iP it's blocked", ...